# Get all the Subchild values using XQUERY-SQL

Tags: xquery-sql

I'm attempting to create an xquery expression that will return all the subchild node values. Now I get only the first subchild under each child.

I have the following XML:

```
<order>
    <child1>
      <subchild id="S1">
        <name type="primary">
          <first>NAOMI</first>
          <middle />
          <last>ADAMS</last>
          <suffix />
        </name>
      </subchild>
      <subchild id="S2">
        <name type="primary">
          <first>TOVER</first>
          <middle />
          <last>DALI</last>
          <suffix />
        </name>
      </subchild>
    </child1>
    <child2>
      <subchild id="V1">
        <year>2002</year>
        <make>PONTI</make>
        <model>AZTEK</model>
        <vin>3G7DA03E32S597676</vin>
      </subchild>
      <subchild id="V2">
        <year>2003</year>
        <make>HONDA</make>
        <model>CIVIC</model>
        <vin>2H94DA03E80S1538</vin>
      </subchild>
    </child2>
    <child3>
      <subchild id="A1">
        <house>7741</house>
        <street1>SAINT BERNARD ST</street1>
        <apartment />
        <city>PLAYA DEL REY</city>
        <state>CA</state>
        <postalcode>90293</postalcode>
      </subchild>
      <subchild id="A2">
        <house>2371</house>
        <street1>HANNUM DR</street1>
        <apartment />
        <city>MARINA DEL REY</city>
        <state>CA</state>
        <postalcode>90293</postalcode>
      </subchild>
    </child3>
  </order>
```

My result should look like :

```
  FirstName LastName    HouseNumber StreetName         City         SState  Zip    Year     Model   Make    VIN
   NAOMI     ADAMS        7741   SAINT BERNARD ST   PLAYA DEL REY     CA    90293   2002    PONTI   AZTEK   G7DA03E32S597676
   TOVER     DALI         2371    HANNUM DR         MARINA DEL REY    CA    90024   2003    HONDA   CIVIC   2H94DA03E80S1538
```

My query :

```
SELECT 
   FirstName, LastName, HouseNumber, StreetName, City, SState, Zip, Year, Model, Make, VIN
FROM 
   xmlTable 
OUTER APPLY 
(  
    SELECT  
       tbl.col.value('(child1/subchild/name/first)[1]','varchar(20)') AS FirstName,
       tbl.col.value('(child1/subchild/name/last)[1]','varchar(20)') AS LastName,
       tbl.col.value('(child1/subchild/name/middle)[1]','varchar(20)') AS MiddleName,
       tbl.col.value('(child3/subchild/house)[1]','varchar(20)') AS HouseNumber,
       tbl.col.value('(child3/subchild/street1)[1]','varchar(20)') AS StreetName,
       tbl.col.value('(child3/subchild/city)[1]','varchar(20)') AS City,
       tbl.col.value('(child3/subchild/state)[1]','varchar(20)') AS SState,
       tbl.col.value('(child3/subchild/postalcode)[1]','varchar(20)') AS Zip,
       tbl.col.value('(child2/subchild/model_year)[1]','varchar(20)') AS Year,
       tbl.col.value('(child2/subchild/model)[1]','varchar(20)') AS Model,
       tbl.col.value('(child2/subchild/make)[1]','varchar(20)') AS Make,
       tbl.col.value('(child2/subchild/vin)[1]','varchar(20)') AS VIN
    FROM 
       xmldocument.nodes('//order') AS tbl(col) 
   )  Y
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you change the XML structure?? This is horribly difficult to do anything useful with this....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 
DECLARE @x XML 
SELECT @x = 'Your XML here'
SELECT   
tbl.col.value('(child1/subchild/name/first)[position() = sql:column("s.number")][1]','varchar(20)') AS FirstName, 
tbl.col.value('(child1/subchild/name/last)[position() = sql:column("s.number")][1]', 'varchar(20)') AS LastName, 
tbl.col.value('(child1/subchild/name/middle)[position() = sql:column("s.number")][1]', 'varchar(20)') AS MiddleName, 
tbl.col.value('(child3/subchild/house)[position() = sql:column("s.number")][1]', 'varchar(20)') AS HouseNumber, 
tbl.col.value('(child3/subchild/street1)[position() = sql:column("s.number")][1]', 'varchar(20)') AS StreetName, 
tbl.col.value('(child3/subchild/city)[position() = sql:column("s.number")][1]', 'varchar(20)') AS City, 
tbl.col.value('(child3/subchild/state)[position() = sql:column("s.number")][1]', 'varchar(20)') AS SState, 
tbl.col.value('(child3/subchild/postalcode)[position() = sql:column("s.number")][1]', varchar(20)') AS Zip, 
tbl.col.value('(child2/subchild/model_year)[position() = sql:column("s.number")][1]', 'varchar(20)') AS Year, 
tbl.col.value('(child2/subchild/model)[position() = sql:column("s.number")][1]', 'varchar(20)') AS Model, 
tbl.col.value('(child2/subchild/make)[position() = sql:column("s.number")][1]', 'varchar(20)') AS Make, 
tbl.col.value('(child2/subchild/vin)[position() = sql:column("s.number")][1]', 'varchar(20)') AS VIN 
FROM @x.nodes('/order') AS tbl(col) 
CROSS JOIN master..spt_values s  
WHERE type = 'P' AND number BETWEEN 1  
AND col.query('count(child1/subchild)').value('.', 'INT')
```

Comment: Or you can use "CROSS JOIN  (Select row_number() over (order by column_id) AS number from sys.columns) AS s WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND ..." in place of master..spt_values s WHERE type = 'P'